# Synchronize linux photos to google photos using an API and node.js

Tags: node.js, synchronization, google-photos

I do have the following issue, I want to create a script in node.js which will recursively synchronize the photos from `Pictures/` folder into my google photos account. And at the moment my issue is how should I approach it cause I didn't find any google photos api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the day it was possible to do the call directly to plus (before the lock down of the `v1whitelisted` API to only registered clients, so this doesn't seem to work anymore unless you violate Google's ToS)

The only available API for Google Photos is the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/)

So you can maybe use something like the [nodejs picasa api client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/picasa)

[You can also experiment by looking over the Protocol Guide](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)

You can further experiment by using the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) through the Picasa API.

Good Luck :)